# Bash 'find' command returns errors destination location is empty

Tags: bash, find

I have this line of code...

```
find $ARCH2_DIR/mysql-bin.* +$BACKUP_PURGE_DAYS -exec rm {} \;
```

The problem I'm having is it's returning an error as per below...

```
find: `/n01/mysqlarch2/mysql-bin.*': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way of not returning this error if the directory is empty?  It is possible that the directory I'm searching is empty and I want the script to carry on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a location to search on.

Try `find "$ARCH2_DIR" -name "mysql-bin.*" +$BACKUP_PURGE_DAYS -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to say except that the value for `--name` must be single quoted.

Comment: @derlarsschneider No, the argument to `-name` here can be double quoted like this just fine. Globs don't expand in either kind of quote. Using single quotes would be "safer" in that it wouldn't expand *anything* where this would try to expand `$` if it were to appear.